# Ember.js action won't play nice with data-toggle=dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an action that takes up the entire row of a table. If the user clicks on that action, he is linked to the next page. However I have a data-toggle=dropdown that toggles a drop down.

My problem arises when I try to click that data-toggle=dropdown and instead/before the dropdown can toggle, I am linked to the next page. I don't want this. I want the link-to action to span across the entire row, but not conflict with any other buttons inside of that row.

```
<tr {{action 'actionThatLinksToNextPage' this.someID bubbles=false}}>
  <td>
    <a  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-sm pull-right btn-sm-big-glyph dropdown-toggle ">
      <div  class="glyphicon fa-lg glyphicon-remove fa-size " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Disabled" role="tooltip" >              
      </div>                
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but that sounds like a confusing UI to me even if what you are trying to accomplish is possible. If the user is expecting to click anywhere inside the row to go somewhere - that probably should always be true.

Comment: I have the same case and it works nice. Just make sure you have a bit bigger padding on the <a> tag that should work.

Comment: @Altrim Would you be able show me in a JSFiddle example? If you word it as an answer, you could get the check if it is correct.

Comment: @KalmanHazins How is this UI confusing to you and why is that relevant to this question? No, it shouldn't be true if the row contains other buttons. This is why bubble=false was created.

Comment: @IanSteffy It's in a big project it would take time to extract it. But the only difference I have is that the wrapping tag in your case <tr> is a component which implements the click event that transitions to a page. And the action that opens the dropdown is in the inside element in your case <a> tag.

Comment: @IanSteffy Dude, if the UI works for you - go for it! :) Maybe I am just misunderstanding the exact scenario. Would love to play with it if you get it to work inside JSBin.

Comment: @IanSteffy Take a look at this jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/natavogegi/1/ . Tried to make a quick example of what I was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you're clicking the dropdown toggle, the event is propagating up the DOM tree to the table row. You need to stop the bubbling before it reaches the `tr` so its action isn't triggered. Something like this should work:

```
$('a[data-toggle=dropdown]').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```